# Please stop telling me my question is subjective

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

Every time I enter a question, I get an annoying popup saying "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed". Titles like "How do you authenticate to Cisco Contact Center Express Identity Service?" or seemingly anything that starts with "How do you..." Even after I dismiss it, it keeps popping back up!

Comment: Maybe you could find another wording ? Something like 'What is the method to authenticate to ...' ? But you should really include research you've done and why they don't answer your question

Comment: These filters aren't intelligent in the slightest. They are pure regex, looking for certain expressions. The easy fix is to stop using the expression that seems to trigger the filter.

Comment: @Patrice They aren't helpful either. I don't let a computer dictate my behavior. I am not a robot and I have free will. Humans are not slaves to machines.

Comment: @Tensibai: I would prefer: "How can I authenticate to..."

Comment: @Chloe well in this situation, the machine will win. You don't want the popup? don't use the expression. I agree it's not helpful, but what do you want to do? The system is in. You tagged this discussion, I'm trying to provide with some kind of solution. Feel free to create a Feature Request to get it undone. Short of that.... not much will move :/

Comment: _"They aren't helpful either. I don't let a computer dictate my behavior. I am not a robot and I have free will. Humans are not slaves to machines."_ So... You'd rather the team dig into the code, figure out how to improve the regex, and fix that than change a word or two in your question title? Just because this is annoying to you, regardless of if it does indeed help other people? (I'm quite sure that yes, it does help at least some people. A large amount? No clue. At least one person? More than likely, with the number of users visiting us per day.)

Comment: @Kendra: To be fair, a tool that causes a significant numbers of false positives should be fixed.

Comment: @NicolBolas Totally agree, I was more addressing that they seem to dislike that they can use the short-term, easy fix of reword the title. Now that they've brought it up here, of course, the team really should look at fixing it. (And sounds like Tim's putting that on the considerations list.)

Comment: ... all else aside, you *do* appear to have a lot of rather subjective and opinion based questions...

Comment: @honk I've choose this wording for a practical meaning where programmatically is obviously implied, how to would be answered with a 'just fill the form and click ok' (omitting the question itself, but that's what the title put in the mind of those clicking on it, and whe' just reading the title it sounds like a customer support question and not a dev question). You're mileage may vary on this kind of title, but I really think it doesn't convey a good first impression when worded 'How to authenticate to x', it looks like yet another dumb Q regardless it's real quality.

Comment: @Tensibai: I see. Thank you for elaborating. To me, the wording "how to" sounds like the title of a manual rather than a question, though. But I'm not a native English speaker...

Answer (score 25):

It's ... a very primitive regex.

I'm not kidding, it has a label:

[image: Site Setting]

If you change 'you' to 'I', it should go through just fine. *More often than not*, the check offers some useful guidance to folks, if only to help narrow the scope of answers they'd like to receive. People tend to remember titles since that's what typically draws them into a question, so you really want "This is how" and less "Well, this is how I usually do it". The latter can set a tone that turns the question into something a bit less useful.

The expression itself is somewhere in the code (not easily tweaked); I've left a note to dust that off and make sure it's still relevant as we audit our on-boarding process for new users altogether, who mostly benefit from that kind of just-in-time (albeit  semi brain-dead) help. If anything, the experience could be quite a bit better (as in a working "Thanks, I got this..." button).

I don't see the harm in raising this sort of thing, it helps us remember that we have stuff easily forgotten that needs revisiting from time to time.

Comment: So would it be triggered if I had a question like "Unable to get video meta-data from You Tube API in my Javascript"? [That sounds like a bug to me.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372974/please-stop-telling-me-my-question-is-subjective#comment623842_372974)

Answer (score 10):

I think it's taking the "How do you..." bit literally as in, "I want to know how each of you do this" instead of figuratively as in, "I want to know how one would accomplish this".

Unfortunately, the site does get questions where people just want to know how other people do stuff so the site does warn you if it looks like that's what you're asking.

You can always just change "How do you..." to "How to...".